# Smooth continuous CSS animation blob flow

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to make a lively blob that blobs smoothly around the shape's plane. However, when I make this approach, the blob is very rigid and the flow of 0-25-50-75-100 can be directly seen in the animation. I am guessing this is because of the ease-in-out transition but I am not sure what to do next. I have tried linear, ease-in, ease-out, and ease-in-out but they are all very choppy

**What should I change to make it a smoother animated blob?**

```css
.shape-container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height:100vh;
}

.shape{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(64deg, #f34868 23%, #f24768 23%, #9e00ec 80%);
  animation: blob 8s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes blob {
  0%, 100% {
    border-radius:65% 100% 80% 100%
  }
  25% {
    border-radius:100% 80% 100% 65%
  }
  50% {
    border-radius:80% 100% 65% 100%
  }
  75% {
    border-radius:100% 65% 100% 80%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="shape-container">
  <div class="shape"/>
</div>
```

**[UPDATE]** This is the 2nd blob I tried, this blob also does not smoothly rotate around, it just goes back and forth

```css
 .shape-container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height:100vh;
}

.shape{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(64deg, #f34868 23%, #f24768 23%, #9e00ec 80%);
  animation: blob 8s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes blob {
  0%, 100% {
    border-radius:24% 76% 35% 65% / 27% 36% 64% 73%
  }
  25% {
    border-radius:76% 24% 33% 67% / 68% 55% 45% 32%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="shape-container">
  <div class="shape"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would have another look at the linear animation timing function because it has the same speed from start to end. Also if you combine the blob animation with a rotate animation you don't easily get the idea there is a pattern in the entire animation.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.shape-container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height:100vh;
  background-color: #222;
}

.shape{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(64deg, #f34868 23%, #f24768 23%, #9e00ec 80%);

  border-radius: 28% 72% 22% 78% / 39% 23% 77% 61%; 
  transform: rotate(0deg); 
  will-change: border-radius, transform;
  
  animation: blob 10s linear infinite, spin 100s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blob {
  0%, 100% {
    border-radius: 28% 72% 22% 78% / 39% 23% 77% 61%; 
  }
  50% {
    border-radius: 72% 28% 50% 50% / 55% 26% 74% 45%;  
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);  
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="shape-container">
  <div class="shape"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting, that rotate is definitely a nice touch... but do you still see that snap when an extended blob part reaches it's maximum stretch? That is the part I am trying to eliminate @Nick Van Loocke

Comment: The snap you mean is probably just the pattern you have determined in your keyframe blob. This looks to me unavoidable (if someone has an idea how to fix this please do tell, I'm also curious now) and if you use the linear animation timing function it al moves at the same speed (so you don't see a hard beginning or end like when you use ease-in-out).

Perhaps another look into a blob can help because you have alot of options to create one, see https://codepen.io/mimikos/pen/oWJjYZ for example (it's an SVG combined with GSAP and this works smoothly but you also can see the pattern in it).